# drop duplicate values and count the values

Tags: python, pandas

I extracted a list of countries and I am trying to process the data to generate a report. I use "`value_counts()`" to count the elements of the countries. The result shows like belows.

```
>>>country_counts
America 10
America England 1
England America 2
Canada America Hongkong 1
Korea 3
```

However, there are some duplicates items where I can't use "`drop_duplicate`" to reduce them. For example, these two values "America England" and "England America" are the same, but appear in different order. I want to only keep one of them and add up the values in the other column.

Just like the following, Change "England America" to "America England" and sum up all of them (2+1=3):

```
America 10
America England 3
Canada America Hongkong 1
Korea 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry not clear, could you please provide more information on your question in your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Edited. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split them on spaces and then sort the list. I have then converted the 
`list` to a `str` so that it can be used in groupby.

```
data = [
        ['America',10],
        ['America England', 1],
        ['England America', 2],
        ['Canada America Hongkong',1],
        ['Korea', 3]
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['a','b'])
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x:str(sorted(x.split(' '))))

print(df.groupby('a').sum())
```

**Output**

```
                                    b
a                                    
['America', 'Canada', 'Hongkong']   1
['America', 'England']              3
['America']                        10
['Korea']                           3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly!